# Switching action bar when doing a key press?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Back in the days I had a macro on which my action bar 2 popped up while holding down shift. When I released shift the action 1 came back up.
I really enjoyed playing it in arena like that.

Can anyone help me creating this macro? I have already searched but the closest I can get is a permanent change on button press.

Comment: Isnt this now changeable in Interface?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Dominos Addon Screenshot]

I use the Dominos addon to assign different bars when modifier keys are pressed.  Shift brings up bar 2, and Alt brings up bar 3.

I have Q, A, Z, X, and 1-4 bound to bar 1.  When shift is held, bar 2 is substituted in and the keys now work with bar 2 (as you'd expect).

When shift is released, bar 1 comes back.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the closest you can get to this without an add on (of which there are probably several) is to show both action bars and set up the bindings on the new bar to be the same buttons on the original plus some modifier. For completeness you show extra action bars under `Interface -> Action Bars*` in the menu.

*Can someone please confirm the name of the sub menu, I do not have access to the game currently, if not I will do so myself later.

For example I have one bar key-bound like:

```
| Q | E | R | T | F | G | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

and the second bar is identical but using shift:

```
| S+Q | S+E | S+R | S+T | S+F | S+G | S+1 | S+2 | S+3 | S+4 | S+5 |
```

Comment: On the note of Addons I believe Bartender has this ability through its paging script box.